# redirecting out/err of a bash script run from python

Tags: python, vba, io-redirection

I'm trying to use `contextlib.redirect...` to redirect err/out of my function:

```
with open(my_file, 'w') as f:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
        print(1)
```

This works fine.

However, I want to run a script:

```
with open(my_file, 'w') as f:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
        os.system('./my_script.sh')
```

and here the out/err is not redirected.

1. Is this because the script is run with its own file descriptors,
   thus, the redirect is not affecting the correct files?
2. Can this be solved from Python rather than redirecting it from the
   Bash script? (`subprocess.checkoutput` maybe? I'm not sure this achieves the same)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Popen`:

```
import subprocess
with open(my_file, 'w') as f:
    subprocess.Popen('./my_script.sh', stdout=f, shell=True)
```

if you want to view the output in python first then save it to a file you can do:

```
with open(my_file, 'w') as f:
    output = subprocess.check_output('./my_script.sh', shell=True)
    print(output)
    f.write(str(output))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems won't work, as in the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

> Note that the global side effect on sys.stdout means that this context manager is not suitable for use in library code and most threaded applications. It also has no effect on the output of subprocesses.

Just try subprocess instead.